# Numeral versus digit?

Tags: numbers

This is a number:

```
123,456,789
```

This is a digit:

```
1
```

And another one:

```
4
```

And another:

```
9
```

So what are ***numerals***? Is this just a synonym for "digit"? Or are digits synonyms for numerals?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: What does your dictionary say ?

Comment: As you have written it, your list is not quite right.  All the examples you give are numbers.  The last three are digits as well as numerals and numbers.  The more common distinction, however has tended to be between numerals and numbers.  Have you tried looking up these distinctions in a dictionary and, among other things, looked to see whether there is any difference between what mathematicians do and what other writers do?

Comment: Not really sure why this question is downvoted. +1

Answer (score 2):

No,

> 123,456,789

is a numeral.  That is, a way of writing a number.  It is not the number itself.

[Reference](https://www.lexico.com/definition/numeral)

> **numeral**  NOUN
>
> 1 A figure, symbol, or group of figures or symbols denoting a number.
>
> 1.1 A word expressing a number.

A *digit*, on the other hand, is indeed a single character, 0-9 in the common Arabic system.

Comment: Added a bit about digits